# Create new sorted vector without duplicates

Tags: c++, vector, unique, std

So far i have this function:

```
std::vector<int> f(std::vector& v)
{
    std::vector<int> result;
    for(unsigned x = 0; x < v.size(); x++)
    {
        std::vector<int>::iterator location = std::find(result.begin(),result.end(),v[x]);
        if(location == result.end())
        {
            result.push_back(this->v[x]);
        }
    }
    std::sort(result.begin(),result.end());
    return result;
}
```

This function returns a sorted vector of elements from v without duplicates.

Is there a more compact way of writing this? I've read about std::unique,but this involves editing the vector which i cannot do.

Comment: Can't you just take `v` by value and `std::sort` and `std::unique` it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you're copying the vector anyway, just do the copy, then sort and unique the result:

```
std::vector<int> f(std::vector<int> v) { 
    using std::begin;
    using std::end;

    std::sort(begin(v), end(v));
    v.erase(std::unique(begin(v), end(v)), end(v));
    return v;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget that passing by value opens up moves as well. A function like this makes more sense not to need an lvalue passed in.

Comment: @chris: yes, especially effective in a case like this where you're taking in the copied/moved item, modifying it, then returning it.

Comment: I certainly see no harm in taking the vector in by value. Certainly passing by non-const reference makes no sense in this case.  This implementation is O(N) + O(n * log(N)), where the original appears to be O(N!) + O(n * log(N)).

Comment: i think both function are correct, if return.size() << v.size() than i would use my version, otherwise this is better.

Answer (score 3):

> I've read about std::unique,but this involves editing the vector which i cannot do.

Make a copy first! Then you can use `unique/erase` in the usual way. In C++03 you would write:

```
std::vector<int> f(const std::vector<int>& v)
//                 ^^^^^ you won't modify v, so make it obvious!
{
    std::vector<int> result(v); // copy the vector
    std::sort(result.begin(),result.end()); // sort it first so that std::unique can work
    std::erase(std::unique(result.begin(),result.end()), result.end()); // just keep the unique elements
    return result;
}
```

If you use C++11 then you can take advantage of move semantics and pass-by-value arguments (it is more efficient when you pass an rvalue to your function and is just as efficient for lvalues), which also allows you to directly modify the argument:

```
std::vector<int> f(std::vector<int> v)
//                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ pass by value
{
    std::sort(v.begin(),v.end()); // sort it first so that std::unique can work
    std::erase(std::unique(v.begin(),v.end()), v.end()); // just keep the unique elements
    return v;
}
```

Thanks @DavidBrown and @chris, I tend to overlook this C++11 idiom since I'm not yet used to it.

Comment: Since you immediately make a copy of the vector you should just pass the vector in by value. This allows [certain optimizations](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/) in some cases.

Comment: @DavidBrown: Ah right, I still forget this one quite often. Funnily enough I see chris made the same comment on Jerry's answer. Fixing it, thanks...

Comment: It's more a case of allowing things to be moved into the parameter. No need to move the parameter into `result`, just use it as is since it's not the original vector.

Comment: @chris: My bad. Fixing it *again*... I really have to get used to this idiom. o_O